# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Form Lookup

Tags: 2013, workflow, form

Is it possible to have a SharePoint 2013 workflow form pull the possible values of a combo box (drop down) with data from an external system (e.g. web service call)? I'm looking to use SharePoint 2013 Workflow to automate some expense management and would like to pull the list of vendors from an external system using a web service call.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Add one external list of vendors using vendor external content type

Step 2:now in Workflow action step you will get this list data.

Comment: Can you please extend this answer with more details, to make it more helpful? :)

Comment: I heard that the new SharePoint 2013 workflow manager can't bind to an external list, is this true?